# Not able to redirect using .htaccess in case of child page( please read the description)

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, server

I am trying to redirect in case of 404. I am able to redirect if the unknown page is on root like
[www.example.com/unknown](http://www.example.com/unknown) than it will be redirected to custom error page using .htaccess but not able redirect page like [www.example.com/newpage.php/unknown](http://www.example.com/newpage.php/unknown) to error page , rather in this it shows the newpage.php without any style
in .htaccess I am using "ErrorDocument 404 /error-404.php" this code.

please help.

Comment: please post your htaccess in order to see what you have so far

Comment: When requesting `newpage.php`, the page is found - i.e. `newpage.php` is located, and receives `/unknown` as an argument. Since the page is found, no 404 is created.

Comment: in .htaccess I have only "ErrorDocument 404 /error-404.php" this , nothing else .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When requesting `newpage.php`, the page is found - i.e. `newpage.php` is located, and receives `/unknown` as an argument. Since the page is found, no 404 is created. This is a feature of the Apache HTTP server, and exposes the path after `newpage.php` through the `PATH_INFO` environment variable (usually available as `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.

You can control this [behaviour through the AcceptPathInfo setting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo), and it can be set in the .htaccess file. To disable the feature, set it to off:

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

> Description:  Resources accept trailing pathname information
>
> Syntax:   AcceptPathInfo On|Off|Default
>
> Default:  AcceptPathInfo Default
>
> Context:  server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess

> This directive controls whether requests that contain trailing pathname information that follows an actual filename (or non-existent file in an existing directory) will be accepted or rejected. The trailing pathname information can be made available to scripts in the `PATH_INFO` environment variable.

> For example, assume the location `/test/` points to a directory that contains only the single file `here.html`. Then requests for `/test/here.html/more` and `/test/nothere.html/more` both collect `/more` as `PATH_INFO`.

The reason for there not being any style applied is that you have a relative link to your stylesheet, and when the path is shown as a subdir of `newpage.php`, the actual request from the browser will be for `/newpage.php/stylesheet.css`.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using only one of the 2 required rules:

```
Redirect 404 /error.php          <- redirect if there is an error
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php     <- redirect if the file is not found
```

Better if you use those at `VirtualHost` level, and not `htaccess` if you want to use those rules everywhere